# Laravel Routing 2 different contact forms going to the same route

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I am using Laravel to build a web app.  I have two contact forms.  One is a main contact form for the website and another one is located on a people page, where USERS can contact a profile.

In app/routes.php I have two routes

```
Route::get(Str::slug(trans('main.contactUrl')), array('uses' => 'HomeController@contact', 'as' => 'contact'));
Route::post(Str::slug(trans('main.contactUrl')), array('uses' =>  'HomeController@submitContact', 'as' => 'submit.contact'));

Route::post(Str::slug(trans('people.contactUrl')), array('uses' => 'HomeActController@submitContactAct', 'as' => 'submit.contact'));
```

For some strange reason, if I use the People contact form to send a message, then I goto the Main Contact form to send a message, the main.contactUrl will follow the route of the people.contactUrl and launch the submitContactAct code.

I know this is happening, because the main.contactUrl starts  throwing errors like Undefined variable: actemail
actemail is a variable I only define in the submitContactAct () function.

Comment: did you check my answer ? does it work for you?

Comment: great @stephenmelb so please accept and +1 the answer so others can find it if they encounter similar problems. cheers

Answer (score 1):

You've got two routes that have the same name 'submit.contact'

```
Route::post(Str::slug(trans('main.contactUrl')), array('uses' =>  'HomeController@submitContact', 'as' => 'submit.contact'));
Route::post(Str::slug(trans('people.contactUrl')), array('uses' => 'HomeActController@submitContactAct', 'as' => 'submit.contact'));

 //                                                          -------v
//array('uses' =>  'HomeController@submitContact', 'as' => 'submit.contact'));
 //                                                                -------v
//array('uses' =>  'HomeActController@submitContactAct', 'as' => 'submit.contact'));
```

Change the name of one of the routes (for example to `submit.contact.act`) and than run `composer dump-autoload`, all should work fine now.